# How to use If Else for check validation is number in Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my code

```
else if(form.txtPrice.IsNumber){
    alert("Price must be number") form.txtPrice.focus();
    return false;
```

I can not check validation must be number in Javascript, everybody help me please, thank you so much!

Comment: `Number(form.txtPrice.value) === NaN`

Comment: Please [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your question, and have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Keith you shouldnt provide answers in comments, it circumvents the voting process which helps determine good/bad/safe/unsafe answers

Answer (score 0):

Use `isNaN(value)`.

This returns `true` if the value is not a number.
If the value is a number, will return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Using only `isNaN` is risky, it has some big inconvenient; These strings will be considered valid numbers:

- 'Infinity'
- '1e355'
- '0xf'
- empty string

you could do more:

```
function isNumber(input) {
  return typeof input === "number" && !isNaN(input);
}
```

note that you have to parse if before if you have a string (parseInt/parseFloat)

Comment: To be fair, they are valid numbers just in different and unexpected formats

Comment: `typeof Infinity , 1e355 , 0xf` are all `number`   There is `Number.isFinite` is you want to prevent those.

Comment: I'm talking about user input strings, for eg. `input = "Infinity";` which is valid number according to `isNaN`. This should disable implicit parsing. Furthermore, `parseInt('Infinity')` returns NaN, which is good IMO

Comment: I still agree they are valid numbers, just not the format you want your users to send